# canon pixma2920 unable to print

Tags: drivers, printing, canon, pixma

I bought a white Canon MG2920 and it worked perfectly the first two months but then out of nowhere it stopped. I only use it for printing and only wireless because I don't have a cable attached. The problem is it just stopped working. When trying to print something it loads the paper but then it's like the paper got stuck and you can hear the printer making a noise trying to get the paper, I guess. I searched for videos on how to get it to work when the paper is stuck and there are a lot of videos for that but when I watch them it looks like those are about a different problem than mine. So please anybody, I would appreciate it if someone could help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple issues here. It could be a driver related issue, or a hardware issue.

[Download](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100626502.html) the driver, and install the package. Then make sure the proper driver is selected for the printer.

If you have done that, you could try to connect the printer via a USB cable to rule out wireless issues.

If that still doesn't fix the issue, you may have a worn out roller or something.